# How to factor polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

How to factor a certain polynomial over $Zn$.

for example factor the following polynomial into irreducible polynomials in $Z5$:

$X^3+X^2+X-1$

or factor the following polynomial into irreducible polynomials in $Z2$:

$X^4+X+1$

is there a certain method (algorithm) I can follow?

Please help I'm stuck and i really need the help!

thank you in advance!!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields.

Comment: The proper term is _over_ rather than _in_ the ring of scalars. May we assume that $n$ is a prime number, or is that not assumed?

Answer (score 2):

let $ f $ be a irreducible polynomial over finite field $\Bbb{F}_q$ and $ \alpha$ is a zero of $f$. let $ d=\mathrm{deg}(f)$. then degree of $\Bbb{F}_q(\alpha)$ is $d$ and the zero is also zero of $ x^{q^d}-x$. therefore all irreducible polynomial with degree $d$ is factor of $x^{q^d}-x$. If $f$ is not a factor of $x^{q^d}-x$, then $f$ is reducible.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is easily proven to be irreducible since a polynomial of degree $\;\le 3\;$ is **reducible** over some field iff it has a root in that field.

For the second one observe that

$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)^2\in\Bbb F_2[x]$$

Comment: But how would I do the factorization using a methodology not just by observation? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: There are several algorithms, e.g., the [Berlekamp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm).